# Auto login to a website using c# , cefsharp and JavaScript

Tags: javascript, c#, cefsharp

I have some serious problem logging into this website automatically
https://olymptrade.com/platform

I'm using c# with cef sharp web browser and javascript. it fills the inputs but when I push the login button it says the fields are empty! here is my code for that in c#:

```
Browser.EvaluateScriptAsync("document.querySelector('input[name=email]').value='MY E_MAIL';");
Browser.EvaluateScriptAsync("document.querySelector('input[name=password]').value='MY PASSWORD';");
Browser.EvaluateScriptAsync("document.querySelector('button[type=submit]').click();");
```

Comment: 1. Have you verified that this is related to cef or does the same happen if you do the same in the browser? 2. It could be due to the methods being async, try adding a delay. 3. Some form validation does not register that the forms has been filled if done w/o using the user interface